# sitecore, setting language based on country or keyboard

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

How can I set the default language based on Country and/or keyboard using the sitecore framework?

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box solution for this. You need to write a custom LanguageResolver. The browser language you can get out of http headers, but for the current country you need a third-party service like MaxMind.

Answer (score 2):

I take your point that you would expect an out of the box solution, but in fact the requirements are often perculiar to the project. That said, here are some thoughts

Creating a custom language resolver is probably the best approach.

**First Attempt**

I normally start by trying to use the the browser language preferences (`HttpRequest.UserLanguages`), which might supply the whole 2-part language 'en-GB', or sometimes just the basic language 'en'.

- If this gave you the whole language, then your're done. Just get the system language with the with the same name.
- If it gave you the basic language only, you need to get the country somehow.
- If it didn't give you anything. You need to get the country, and find a default language for that country.

**Getting the Country**

If you go with the MaxMind option, you should probably use the the GeoLite version locally, as you can't rely on the DMS Geo IP lookup being performed in a timely manner.

- If the lookup is successful, and you already had a basic language then you should now have 2-part language to compare against your system languages.
- If the lookup was successful, but you don't have basic language, then you need to get a default. In the past, I have created a 'Language Mapping' template with 2 fields. A 'Country code' text field, and a 'Language' droplink source to the list of system language. When you have obtained the country code, you simply look it up in your mapping items, and set the context language accordingly.

**Some things to consider**

- Remember you need to have some sort of fallback for when the lookups haven't worked.
- Perhaps store the language as a cookie, so the lookup is not done every time.